# Meu código do meu slide jquery cycle 2 não funciona. Queria saber onde está o erro?

Tags: jquery, html, cycle2

Estou a muito tempo tentando fazer esse slide funcionar, mas, não funciona de jeito nenhum, queria ajuda de vcs.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código HTMl:

```css
.slideshow{
    width:100%;
    max-width:980px;
 overflow:hidden;
    height:505px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.slides{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}

.slide-1{
    width:80%;
    height:505px;
    float:left;
}

.slide-2{
    width:20%;
    height:250px;
    float:left;
}

.slide-3{
    width:20%;
    height:250px;
    float:left;
}

.slide-1 img{
 width:635px;
 height:500px;
}

.slide-2 img{
 width:345px;
 height:250px;
 margin-left:-150px;
}

.slide-3 img{
 width:345px;
 height:250px;
 margin-left:-150px;
}

#btn-slide{
 margin-top:-320px;
}

#btn-next{
 float:right;
 position:relative;
 left:-94px;
}

#btn-prev{
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 left:90px;
 margin-top:-4px;
}

/*-----------Fim da Config. do slideshow------------*/

.info-slide-left{
 font-family:Arial,Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
 font-size:1.563em;
 width:650px;
 margin-top:-180px;
 margin-left:10px;
 line-height:1.68em;
}

.info-slide-left  a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#000;
}

.info-slide-left a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline; 
}

.info-slide-rigth{
 font-family:Arial,Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
 font-size:13px;
 width:400px;
 margin-top:-100px;
 margin-left:-140px;
 line-height:22px;
}

.info-slide-rigth a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#000;
}

.info-slide-rigth a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline; 
}

.info-slide-right-3{
 font-family:Arial,Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
 font-size:13px;
 width:400px;
 margin-top:-100px;
 margin-left:-140px;
 line-height:22px;
}

.info-slide-right-3 a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#000;
}

.info-slide-right-3 a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline; 
}

.seta-direita:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    margin-top:-920px;

    border-top: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid #FF7F00;
}

.seta-direita p{
 z-index:99; 
    margin-left:14px;
    font-family:Arial,Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
 margin-top:-500px;
}

.seta-direita-2:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
 position:relative;
 top:-208px;

    border-top: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid #FF7F00;
}

.seta-direita-2 p{
 z-index:99; 
    margin-left:14px;
    font-family:Arial,Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
 position:relative;
 top:-246px;
}

.seta-direita-3:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
 position:relative;
 top:-208px;

    border-top: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid #FF7F00;
}

.seta-direita-3 p{
 z-index:99; 
    margin-left:14px;
    font-family:Arial,Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
 position:relative;
 top:-246px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>

<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slides">

    <div class="slide-1">
     <a href="#"><img src="img/01.jpg"></a>
     <div class="info-slide-left">
     
       <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria.</h2></a>  
       <div class="seta-direita">
        <p>Categoria #1</p>
       </div>
        
         
     </div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="slide-2">
     <a href="#"><img src="img/img02.jpg"><a/>
     <div class="info-slide-rigth">
     
       <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria.</h2></a>
       <div class="seta-direita-2">
        <p>Categoria #1</p>
       </div>
       
       
       </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="slide-3">
    
     <a href="#"><img src="img/img02.jpg"></a>
     <div class="info-slide-right-3">
     
       <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria.</h2></a> 
       <div class="seta-direita-3">
        <p>Categoria #1</p>
       </div>
        
     </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  <div class="slide"><!--Grupo 2 de slide-->

    <div class="slide-1">
     <a href="#"><img src="img/01.jpg"></a>
     <div class="info-slide-left">
     
       <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria.</h2></a>  
       <div class="seta-direita">
        <p>Categoria #1</p>
       </div>
        
         
     </div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="slide-2">
     <a href="#"><img src="img/img02.jpg"><a/>
     <div class="info-slide-rigth">
     
       <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria.</h2></a>
       <div class="seta-direita-2">
        <p>Categoria #1</p>
       </div>
       
       
       </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="slide-3">
    
     <a href="#"><img src="img/img02.jpg"></a>
     <div class="info-slide-right-3">
     
       <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria.</h2></a> 
       <div class="seta-direita-3">
        <p>Categoria #1</p>
       </div>
        
     </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  

  </div><!--Fim do 2 Slide-->
</div><!--Fim da div slideshow-->

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

Código Javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('.slideshow').cycle({
      speed: 600,
      manualSpeed: 100
   });
});
```

Comment: @Marconi jquery cycle 2

Comment: É bem simples a implementação, vê se é isso que você quer http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/BvgU3/15/ , se for posto na resposta explicando o código

Comment: @Brunno vou colocar a foto do designer do meu slide

Comment: OK a implementação é mais simples do que eu postei, o javascript está grande por conta do menu em baixo, se retirar o menu fica levinho ;)

Comment: @Brunno poste como resposta.

Comment: @Brunno ai esta o designe do meu slide

Comment: @Brunno não entedi que vc quis dizer ?

Comment: @GilmarSantos, essa implementação que fiz, foi em um html meu, quando chegar em casa eu faço o slide funcionar no seu html que você postou a cima :D

Comment: @Brunno Se vc fizer isso por, ficarei muito agradecido !

Comment: @GilmarSantos conforme te prometi, segue o fiddle da implementação em cima do seu html http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/BvgU3/17/ sua versão do jquery está ok não esquente com isso. E não mexi no css, pode ser que alguma imagem sobrescreva algo, mais é tudo detalhe de css. :D qualquer coisa estou a disposição

Comment: @Brunno só tenho que lhe agradecer, vc me ajudou muito. Muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Estou tentando criar um site ha muito tempo e agora vc adiantou o meu trabalho !!

Answer (score 2):

Duas coisas, primeiro, veja se a versão do jquery que está usando é compatível com o plugin cycle. Segundo o style que você está usando (". slideshow") não encontrei no teu código. Até onde sei vc precisa usar a seguinte estrutura:

```
<div id="<id-qualquer>">   
<img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200">   
<img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200">   
<img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200"> 
</div>

$(function() {
   $('#<id-qualquer>').cycle();
});
```

Abaixo um exemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#fade').cycle();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>


<div id="fade" class="pics" style="position: relative; overflow: visible;">
  <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200">
  <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200">
  <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200">
</div>
```

Comment: +1 nem consegui achar o CDN do puglin rsrsrs.

Comment: @Gilmar Santos veja agora com o exemplo

Comment: o class slideshow é a primeira div do código

Comment: Está aqui @Marconi: http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

Comment: @GilmarSantos acredito que seja tua estrutura que esteja incorreta. Tente efetuar o teste que te falei com o jquery 1.7

Comment: @EmirMarques vou fazer isso

Comment: @EmirMarques não deu certo o teste com jquery 1.7

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29459/discussion-between-gilmar-santos-and-emir-marques).

Answer (score 2):

A implementação é bem simples, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

HTML:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx="fadeout" data-cycle-auto-height="4:3" data-cycle-delay="-1500" style="height: 222px; overflow: hidden;">    
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg" data-cycle-fx="tileBlind" class="first cycle-slide">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg" class="cycle-slide">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg" data-cycle-fx="tileBlind" class="cycle-slide">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg" class="cycle-slide cycle-slide-active">        
</div>
```

CSS "Opcional":

```
span.cycle-pager-active {
    background-color: #ff0;
}
.cycle-slideshow, .cycle-slideshow img {
    width: 500px;
}
.my-pager span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('div.cycle-slideshow').cycle('goto');
});
```

Segue [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/BvgU3/16/) para visualização :D

Comment: @GilmarSantos, não esqueça de setar como [Resolvido](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/30045) assim você ajuda a comunidade e me ajuda :D